# How to delete last word from a string using jquery

Tags: javascript

i have a string that is--

```
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i>
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon fa fa-folder-open icon-state-warning icon-lg jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>
hello
```

I want to remove hello in this string and add any other word. I want to know how do I remove that word and how to add another word in place of hello.

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag and added the Javascript tag.  jQuery is a library built with Javascript.  Whilst you may use it to get a DOM element that contains that string (somehow), you wouldn't use it to parse the string.  You just need Javascript for that.  Now, please read [ask] and fix your question before it ends up closed.

Comment: [This](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/05/removing-character-startend-string-javascript/) can help you

Comment: Define a word. Cause a word in your case is not split by a space, but the `>` operator. Is it always like this, or is it sometimes spaces before the word?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can just do it with plain JS

```
var str = 'i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation">hello';
var n = str.lastIndexOf(">");
var replace = str.substr(n+1);
var replaceWith = "test";
var afterReplacement = str.replace(replace, replaceWith);
```